# Laravel + Vuex: Object/argument destructuring not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, vuex, laravel-mix

I'm building a Vue application using Vuex, and I can't get the following code to work (edited for brevity, inspired by [this blog post](https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2017/04/25/vuejs-two-way-data-binding-state-management-vuex-strict-mode/)).

```
// File: views/Board.vue

export default {
    methods: {
        updateProp (prop, value) {
            console.log(prop, value) // Outputs prop and value

            this.$store.commit('board/updateProp', {
                [prop]: value
            })
        }
    },

    // ...
}
```

And in my (named) Vuex module:

```
// File: vuex/modules/board.js

export default {
    mutations: {
        updateProp (state, { prop, value }) {
            console.log(prop, value) // Outputs 'undefined undefined'
        }
    },

    // ...
}
```

Because `import { something } from 'somewhere'` works fine, I'm inclined to believe object destructuring *works*. I'm just baffeled why my code doesn't.

I've also created a `.babelrc` file with the following, and installed the respective plugins and presets, but to no avail.

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ],
    "presets": [
        ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
    ]
}
```

Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the answer, but too difficult to fit into a comment. I'm not sure why both `prop` and `value` are `undefined`, but that isn't how destructuring works (it does not unpack the key and value of an object). The current setup would only work if you are calling it with an object that has a `prop` key and a `value` key:

```
this.$store.commit('board/updateProp', { prop, value })
```

Comment: It may not be the answer to why my code isn't working (which appeared to work for whoever wrote the blog post), but your suggestions _does_ work for me and feels equally elegant if not more so. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad I was able to help you out!